# Is mysql column order in condition influence query performance?

Tags: mysql, indexing

There is a table `foo`, it has `user_id` and `status` columns and others, and both `user_id` and `status` are indexed, e.g.

```
key idx_status (status)
key idx_user_id (user_id)
```

and `count(distinct user_id)` more than `count(distinct status)`.

Now I want to execute a sql, e.g.

```
select * from foo where status = '00' and user_id = 100000 ;
```

My colleague suggests that I should put `user_id` before `status` in above  sql condition. He said if so the sql will use `idx_user_id` first then use `idx_status`, clearly the performance is better.

But I'm not sure, I think mysql will optimized it no matter how the order of sql condition. So I think the order in condition could arbitrarily.

Which is right?
BTW I explained the sqls and did not found any diff, both are:

```
         id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
    table: foo
     type: ref
possible_keys: idx_status,idx_userid
      key: idx_userid
  key_len: 123
      ref: const
     rows: 7
 filtered: 100.00
    Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

Answer (score 2):

Mysql will rewrite the query to use the most selective index (idx_userid in your case). An you see this in the results of EXPLAIN.

However, for the query it is better to have a composite (user_id, status) index.

Comment: Thanks! Could you know some official links about this? I want to know more.

Comment: and I want to have sufficient evidence to supply to my colleague.

Comment: I have two links (to my own blogs) that would recommend a composite index in your case:  [index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [compound indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) .